# Copy row to another tab, getFormulas, clearContent, setFormulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make google sheets automatically copy a row and paste it to the bottom of another tab when Completed is selected from a dropdown in the 8th column. Then I want it to grab the formulas from that row, clear the row, and then replace the formulas.  The code works as far as copying and pasting to the other tab but I can't get it to grab the formulas, clear the row and then replace the formulas.  I can't even get it to clear the row. The code is correctly executing everything but the last four lines.

This isn't my code.  I got it from a website and modified it to fit my sheet.  I have a very basic understanding of javascript. I need the original row to remain with just the formulas populated so that it can be reused.  I'm using copyTo instead of moveTo because the row is being referenced upstream by another sheet and moveTo causes the formulas on the upstream spreadsheet to auto update to the new location of the data instead of continuing to reference the original row. Thank you for any help.

```
function myStorage() {

 // moves a row from a sheet to another when a value is entered in a column

 var sheetNameToWatch = "In Progress";

 var columnNumberToWatch = 8;

 var valueToWatch = "Completed";

 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Storage";



 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();



 if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);

   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);

// this is where it stops working.  I'm not sure how to grab just the row of the active cell and do the following

   var clearRange = sheet.getRange(range.getRow());

   clearRange.getFormulas();

   clearRange.clearContent();

   clearRange.setFormulas();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function CallItSomethingElse(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=="In Progress" && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.value=="Completed") {
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Storage");
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
    var clearRange=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
    var fA=clearRange.getFormulas();//returns a 2d array of formulas
    clearRange.clearContent();
    clearRange.setFormulas(fA);//you have to add that array back into this line
  }
}
```

> Because many people will take this code and try to run it from the editor just to return and tell me that they get the error of cannot find method getSheet of undefined.  Let me first suggest that you can't run this code without an event object.  The single e is the parameter that the event object will be place into.  Without the e the program cannot run.  Also unless there is a trigger to create the e the script cannot run.  So if you wish to run this from the script editor then you will have to provide the event object.  I don't choose to do that so when I debug these things I do it will a live trigger.

Comment: Thank you!  This is working.  It is pasting to the Storage sheet twice, though, so there's two rows pasted there for each row marked Completed and copied.

Comment: Edit: The first three times I tested this, it was double copying to the Storage sheet but the three tests I just performed did not do that.  It only copied once.  Not sure what caused it on those first three but it seems to be working now.  Thank you!

Comment: Just tested it again and it's double pasting.  Weird that it's inconsistently doing that.

Comment: I made a few changes. Please try it again

Comment: I tested it twice.  The first time it pasted once and the second time it pasted twice. The trigger is set to execute on edit. Could it be something else on my end causing it or lag maybe?

Comment: Did you create a trigger for it?  Is it still name onEdit(e)?  Try deleting your trigger if you created a trigger for it.  I suspect your have two triggers on it.

Comment: That's what I originally suspected but I just have one trigger set for onEdit.  I deleted the first one.  I'm going to try deleting the trigger and script and starting from scratch.  If nothing else, I can try to add a script that will delete duplicate rows on the Storage tab.

Comment: Please delete that trigger or rename the function to something other than onEdit()

Comment: I deleted the trigger, renamed the function and recreated the trigger.  For whatever reason, that seems to have fixed it.  I can't replicate the double pasting now and I tested about 15 rows. It was doubling every few tests before.  Thanks!!!

Comment: It was getting the trigger for simple triggers and your trigger at the same time.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks again!